# Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I want to tap on TitledBottomNavigationBar item using Button inside another widget.
I am only using the key in navigation bar it still says that i'm using it still says `Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:titled_navigation_bar/titled_navigation_bar.dart';

class TesterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesterPageState createState() => _TesterPageState();
}

class _TesterPageState extends State<TesterPage> {
  final GlobalKey _navigationBarKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: TitledBottomNavigationBar(
        key: _navigationBarKey,
        onTap: (int index) {
          print(index.toString());
        },
        items: [
          TitledNavigationBarItem(title: 'Home', icon: Icons.home),
          TitledNavigationBarItem(title: 'Help', icon: Icons.help),
          TitledNavigationBarItem(title: 'Account', icon: Icons.person),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Test"),
          onPressed: () {
            final TitledBottomNavigationBar navigationBar = _navigationBarKey.currentWidget;
            navigationBar.onTap(1);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It throws error:

```
I/flutter ( 3573): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3573): The following assertion was thrown building
I/flutter ( 3573): TitledBottomNavigationBar-[GlobalKey#03b8b](dependencies: [_InheritedTheme,
I/flutter ( 3573): _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#4d232], MediaQuery], state: _TitledBottomNavigationBarState#4cc2f):
I/flutter ( 3573): Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
I/flutter ( 3573): The key [GlobalKey#03b8b] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were:
I/flutter ( 3573): - MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(411.4, 868.6), devicePixelRatio: 3.5, textScaleFactor: 0.9,
I/flutter ( 3573):   platformBrightness: Brightness.dark, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
I/flutter ( 3573):   alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: falsedisableAnimations: falseinvertColors:
I/flutter ( 3573):   falseboldText: false))
I/flutter ( 3573): - TitledBottomNavigationBar-[GlobalKey#03b8b](dependencies: [_InheritedTheme,
I/flutter ( 3573):   _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#4d232], MediaQuery], state: _TitledBottomNavigationBarState#4cc2f)
I/flutter ( 3573): A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
```

Comment: I think it's a problem with `TitledBottomNavigationBar`.  I skimmed over its code, and it looks like it reuses the supplied key.  I see that [you've already filed an issue about it](https://github.com/pedromassango/titled_navigation_bar/issues/8). Can you use a `ValueKey` instead?

Comment: @jamesdlin i used `GlobalKey` because of `.currentWidget` property. I think `ValueKey/LocalKey` doesn't fit here.

Comment: Why can't you use a `ValueKey` with a unique string?

Comment: @jamesdlin by using `ValueKey` can i access `onTap()` method of `TitledBottomNavigationBar`?

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @jamesdlin a little example will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: For example, declare `_navigationBarKey` as `final Key _navigationBarKey = ValueKey('myNavigationBarKey');` (or with whatever string you want, as long as you don't reuse it elsewhere in your application for another `TitledBottomNavigationBar`).

Comment: @jamesdlin This is what i was saying: Only `GlobalKey` has property of `currentWidget`. Error: `The getter 'currentWidget' isn't defined for the class 'Key'.
Try importing the library that defines 'currentWidget', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'currentWidget'.`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue using the minimal repro you've provided. Since TitledBottomNavigationBar is unavailable, I used Flutter's readily available BottomNavigationBar.

On your code, TitledBottomNavigationBar needs to be casted on the widget key to be that specified widget.

```dart
final TitledBottomNavigationBar navigationBar = 
    _navigationBarKey.currentWidget! as TitledBottomNavigationBar;
```

Then to update the TitledBottomNavigationBar's current index, setState should be called inside onTap(int).

```dart
currentIndex: _currentPage,
onTap: (int index) {
  debugPrint('Current index: $index');
  if (index != _currentPage) {
    setState(() => _currentPage = index);
  }
},
```

Here's the complete sample.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey _navigationBarKey = GlobalKey();
  int _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            BottomNavigationBar navigationBar =
                _navigationBarKey.currentWidget! as BottomNavigationBar;
            debugPrint('Key $navigationBar');
            navigationBar.onTap!(2);
            // navigationBar.onTap(1);
          },
          child: const Text('Tap me!'),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        key: _navigationBarKey,
        currentIndex: _currentPage,
        onTap: (int index) {
          debugPrint('Current index: $index');
          if (index != _currentPage) {
            setState(() => _currentPage = index);
          }
        },
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Home', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Help', icon: Icon(Icons.help)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Account', icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]